# Styling Drupal Footer

Tags: drupal, footer

I am using drupal version 7 and using Professional Theme 7.x-2.04.

I have text "Copyright Lifestyle Interiors 2015". It is left aligned by default. I need to make it Centre Aligned and make the format as bold , how do I do that?

Comment: By using CSS you can make that

Answer (score 0):

I have got it now how to do it. I was unable to locate the css file earlier.Open the page where footer is located in chrome. For firefox use firebug. Right on the Footer -> Choose Inspect element

Here move to the css section

```
#copyright {
  clear:both;
  padding:0 20px;
  box-shadow:0 -1px 3px #ccc;
  background:#CCC;
  color:#000;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
```

add text-align:center; to your code see the results.

Now do the same in original css file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove credits (or merge them with copyright `<p>`) from `page.tpl.php`

```html
<p class="credits"> Theme Originally Created by  <a href="http://www.devsaran.com">Devsaran</a></p>
```

In `style.css`:

1. Add `text-align: center;` into `#copyright`:

```css
#copyright {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #ccc;
    clear: both;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

2. Delete or comment out `.copyright`

```css
/*.copyright {
    float: left;
    max-width: 728px;
}*/
```